# Creating rows in a table when data is missing for some columns

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, algorithm

I have a javascript object that looks similar to:

```
    const relevantTags = {
        "tags": {
            date: {
                day: "day",
                month: "month",
                year: "year"
            },
            time: {
                hours: "hours",
                minutes: "minutes"
            },
            adm: {
                admId: "adm-id"
            },
            document: {
                documentId: "document-id",
                documentGeneratedBy: "document-generated-by",
                approvalStatus: "approval-status"
            },
            department: {
                departmentName: "department-name"
            }
        }
}
```

Here the keys `date`, `time`, `adm`, `document` and `department` are table headings and the values for each table-heading object are the column values. For example, when the column heading is `document`, one of the value of it's column is `document-generated-by`. Similarly, when the column heading is `department`, one of it's column value is `department-name`. As could be seen, some columns have more values than others.

I am trying to generate a table from this javascript object.

I generated the table head as :

```
 const tableHead = (
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {Object.keys(relevantTags.tags).map(pts => (
        <th scope="col">{pts}</th>
      ))}
    </tr>
  </thead>
);
```

I am not sure how could I generate table rows/columns. How could I do this? I want to create a dynamic table, similar to the snippet I have given below:

```
<table>
  {tableHead}
  <tbody>
    {tableRows}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note: All keys inside javascript object are dynamic and not fixed. They could be present/absent at times, depending on some configuration.**

Table based on the number of columns would look similar to:

[image]

As you could see, time column has more number of rows as compared to other columns.

For the above data structure table would looks similar to:

```
date  time    adm     document              department

day   hours   adm-id  document-id           department-name
month minutes         document-generated-by
year                  approval-status
```

Comment: Do you just want to render empty cells if the value is not present for that column?

Comment: I don't think that the data you presented is suitable to be rendered as a table. Tables are row-based so every row has a value for each column. What you have here is more like a collection of lists that share no common attributes.

Comment: @trixn Yes, just want to render the empty cells.

Comment: Could you please add an example of how the table would look like given the above example of tags?

Comment: @trixn Have updated my question with how the table would look with the example data.

Comment: I see. So as I said, this is not a data structure that you would present as a table. In a table every row usually shares common attributes where each attribute has its own column. In your example the rows don't have anything in common. You could use something like flexbox or css-grid to display several lists next to each other to achieve something like that but I wouldn't use a table.

Comment: @trixn Could you suggest a way with flexbox? I read about flexbox and it looks a better option.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @trixn , flexbox is much better suited for this scenario.

You could approach in the following way:

```
 const flexHead = (
    <div className="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
        {Object.keys(relevantTags.tags).map(pts => (
        <div className="p-d-1">
            <span className="uppercase muted small">{pts}</span>
            <div className="d-flex flex-column">
            {Object.values(relevantTags[pts]).map(dts => (
                <div className="p-d-1">
                <Tag onClick={this.onTagSelection} color="blue">
                    {dts}
                </Tag>
                </div>
            ))}
            </div>
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    );
```

Here is the corresponding CSS:

```
        .d-flex {
            display: flex!important;
        }

        .flex-column {
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
            -ms-flex-direction: column!important;
            flex-direction: column!important;
        }

        .flex-row {
            -webkit-box-orient: horizontal!important;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
            -ms-flex-direction: row!important;
            flex-direction: row!important;
        }

        .flex-wrap {
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap!important;
            flex-wrap: wrap!important;
        }

        .p-d-1 {
           padding: 0.10rem !important;
        }

        .muted {
          color: #6c757d !important;
          font-family: "Muli"
        }

        .small {
           font-size: 85%;
           font-weight: 400;
        }
```

You could then use `flexHead` directly in your render method. For the mock that I created, it came out something like this:

[image]